Partial inference with typescript generics
Is there any way to pass an argument to a generic type and infer another ? I've tried the following but it shows all possible way.
I cannot pass the state as it, otherwise this would allow the user to play with a reactive object by mutating it, where I want it to only subscribe to it.
type A = {
  value: string;
  number: number;
}

subscribe<AnotherState extends {}>(
  roomId: string,
  key: keyof AnotherState,
  callback: (
    state: AnotherState[typeof key]
  ) => void
): UnsubscribeFunction;

// can call
subscribe<A>("test", "value", (isAString) => console.log(isAString));
subscribe<A>("test", "number", (isANumber) => console.log(isANumber));

// final implementation
subscribe: (roomId, key, callback) => {
  const targetState = roomStateMap.get(roomId);
  if (!targetState) throw new Error(`Room ${roomId} not found`);

  return subscribeKey(targetState, key, callback);
},

Thanks

Since subscribe is generic, TS can't infer the exact callback's argument's type, I would suggest to use a function factory to create a non-generic (the parameter is inferred) subscribe() function:
Playground
type A = {
 value: string;
 number: number;
}

declare function subscriber<AnotherState extends {}>(
    roomId: string
) : <K extends keyof AnotherState>(
    key: K,
    callback: (state: AnotherState[K]) => void
  ) => Function;

const subscribe = subscriber<A>("test")
subscribe("value", (isAString) => console.log(isAString)); // string
subscribe("number", (isANumber) => console.log(isANumber)); // number


Awesome. Even better for readability. Thanks
